# How can i show the image name when i taking a picture?

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to show the name of the image i take with my Camera but i dont know how.
Do i need a another function to show the image name?

My Code for taking picture:

```
    Public Function takePicture() As String
    Dim url = THETA_URL & "commands/execute"
    Dim payload = New Dictionary(Of Object, Object) From {
            {"name", "camera.takePicture"}
        }
    Dim request As Net.WebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
    request.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(THETA_ID, THETA_PASSWORD)
    Dim resp As Net.WebResponse = request.GetResponse()

End Function
```

Comment: You're still not reading the Response Stream and still not specifying what you're trying to download. What is the Image format that, sooner or later, will be streamed to you? What is the Stream content? Simply a sequence of bytes or does it have a specific format that needs to be decoded / interpreted?

Comment: Im trying to get the name(url) of the image(jpg) i took. I got the request and response.     Here is the request `Function post(osc_command As String) As String
        Dim url = THETA_URL + osc_command
        Dim request As Net.WebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
        request.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(THETA_ID, THETA_PASSWORD)
        Dim resp As Net.WebResponse = request.GetResponse()

    End Function `

Comment: Yes, this is already in your post. You haven't answered any of my questions, except that the final *product* will be a JPEG format, in a way or another. -- You're not reading the Response Stream, so you're not actually receiving anything at this time. -- When you will read that Stream and get the Image, see the [Image.PropertyItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem) or [BitmapMetadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapmetadata), depending on what assemblies you prefer to use.

Comment: So i need to read the Stream to receive the name of the image?

Comment: If, as mentioned, the Stream just returns the Image bytes, then yes, you have to read the EXIF metadata from the Image itself, unless the API you're streaming from is providing this information in some other way. This is part of the device documentation.

Comment: Unless, with *the name of the image*, you mean the file name. If that's the case, it could be in the Response Headers, in Content-Disposition. This Header is not mandatory or required by the transaction, so it may or may not be there. Also, the Headers can contain anything: it's possible that the device is adding custom Headers that add more details about the requested resource. This should also be part of the documentation (or, just read the Headers and see what's in there)

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know and what does the code look like (I'm new)

Comment: Why `New Dictionary(Of Object, Object)`? You are providing 2 strings. Why not `(Of String, String)` Try to avoid Object whenever possible.

Comment: Functions need a Return statement. Don't ask what you should return. What do you want to return? You have declared it to be a String so what String do you want to return? If you don't need a return value make the method a Sub.

Answer (score 1):

See the line where is says:

```
    End Function
```

Look in the line numbers margin; next to it there is a blank bar (mine is dark gray in my theme) - click in it to put a red dot:

[image]

End Function will go red too..

Then run your code and retrieve your image. The code will stop with a yellow bar pointing to End Function

Take a look at the bottom of VS - you'll either have an Autos window or a Locals window - either one will do. It will show the response object and you can drill into it like a tree, open the headers collection, have a look if anything in it contains the data you want.. It also thus tells you how to get the data you want out of it..

[image]

e.g. if I wanted the "Content-Disposition" value I could say `resp.Headers("Content-Disposition")` - AllKeys is showing me what available strings I can use to index the headers collection

Content-Disposition probably won't list a filename on its own - it'll be something more involved like `"attachment; filename=someimage.jpg"` so you'll need to pull the data you want out of it. Don't get your hopes up if this is a basic cam; it's unlikely to have any meaningful sort of filename. It might be IMG_0001 etc, if it's there at all - I think you should instead make your own name up, as you'll be able to put more info into it, it will be more meaningful than what you get from the cam (and if the cam doesn't send a filename you'll have to do it anyway)

Comment: wow thx, i swa some microsoft doku they said i need a Stream to get the image name or something.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-retrieve-a-protocol-specific-webresponse-that-matches-a-webrequest

Comment: Can you please show me how exactly the code looks like?

Comment: I can't, because I don't have your camera. I don't know for certain it puts a Content-Disposition header, or what it looks like. I don't know what kind of name you want.. But honestly I'd just make one up that suited my purpose

Comment: You can use [ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.contentdispositionheadervalue.parse) to extract the parts. It provides a `FileName` property. E.g., `dim fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(resp.Headers("Content-Disposition")).FileName`